# How to loop over all edges in a directed graph and get source + destination

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I've added a bunch of nodes and vertices to my directed graph, created with settings typedef `boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Node, Edge> graph;`

`Node` has a string for the node's name, and `Edge` has an int for its score.  I am trying to loop over all the edges and output the source and target names, as well as the score for that edge.

You can get an iterator over the edges with `my_graph.m_edges.begin()`, which can be dereferenced to get `m_source` and `m_target`.

How do I get the names assigned to the source and target nodes, as well as the score on that edge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an `edge_descriptor` `e`, you can use `my_graph[source(e, my_graph)].name`, `my_graph[target(e, my_graph)].name`, and `my_graph[e].score` to get the information you are asking about.